# Xamarin Android App Slowing Down/Crashing when selecting images

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I followed this tutorial - https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/

But the issue is when I have selected the images I want to use and display, there is a delay and it takes a very long time to display these images, it is just a black screen for quite a while.

Sometimes it will just crash. There is no issue with the iOS version as it is working perfectly.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It may be a memory issue. In the project properties, under Android Options -> Advanced, try setting the Java Max Heap to 1G

Comment: Is this a Xamarin-Android project or a Xamarin-Forms project?

Comment: @Glaucus Xamarin-Forms project

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher Just tried this, but it doesn't help it

Comment: it does sound like a possible memory leak is happening. Can you monitor the memory footprint using the Xamarin profiler? I haven't looked at the tutorial you posted, but keep in mind that the Xamarin examples and tutorials don't always follow the best practices.

Comment: @Ciaran 1) That code is not very memory friendly on Android as the images are not being released/recycled (`Bitmap.recycle()`), in general that code should be profiled as it will show the issues very quickly when selecting multiple bitmaps. 2) Next before those images are shown, they should be resized based upon the device resolution and the size of the cell they are being shown in.